# How should I use android developer page correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am completely new on developing Android OS and having difficulty using https://developer.android.com/

I want to adjust the advices written on the page but I think I do not understand how to at all .

For example, I am now seeing https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator

and seeing the xml code such as

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:repeatCount="1"
            android:repeatMode="reverse">
    <propertyValuesHolder android:propertyName="x" android:valueTo="400"/>
    <propertyValuesHolder android:propertyName="y" android:valueTo="200"/>
</objectAnimator>
```

I pasted this on the view xml file but it does not work at all.

Could anybody please tell me how to use the page correctly ?

Comment: Read up on resources. An ObjectAnimator is not a view that can be put in a layout file. It is an `anim` resource that goes in its own file. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Comment: Please clarify what you trying to do. I don't know what `use android developer page correctly` means.